# Openshot creating videos within a box.

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, openshot, borders

Openshot 1.4.3 Ubuntu 16.04 - No matter what profile I use or target codec... the output of the video file all end up with a 1inch black border on all sides. VLC settings working just fine when watching other videos but anything I create using openshot is boxed in.
Decided to try out Openshot 2.2 and in 15min, I gave that up real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Brain f*rt! Right Click on the video clip, Properties, Video and uncheck "Maintain Aspect Ratio" (Normally only create videos once a year, oops!).